# What is the $\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sqrt{x^2+1}/x)$?

Tags: calculus, limits

After L'Hospital's Rule, it becomes from: $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}\right)$$

to this:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)$$

And after doing it again it just goes back to the first form. What am I doing wrong? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can assume $\;x>0\;$ , so

$$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}x=\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}1$$

Answer (score 3):

$$
L = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)
$$
so
$$
L^2 = \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}\right)  \lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right) = 1
$$

Comment: Very nice trick...but it depends on **first** proving the limit exists finitely, otherwise arithmetic of limits isn't appliable.

Comment: yes, good point! does the fact that $\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x} - \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = \frac1{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}$ help with this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, yet it is easy to show the function $\;\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}x\;$ is monotonic descending and bounded from below on, say $\;x\in[1,\infty)\;$  and thus the limit exists.

Answer (score 2):

Lets call $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}}{x}$$ then by L'hopital we have that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{f(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$$
If $f(x)$ converges to $L$ where $L\in[-\infty,\infty]$ then 
$$\frac{1}{L}=L$$ and since $L>0$ we have $L=1$

Answer (score 0):

Take out $x^2$ from root and $x$ will cut with bottom one you can easily get the answer!

Comment: What do you mean by "take out $x^2$ from root" and "$x$ will cut with bottom one"?